# Can characters with more HP survive falling from a greater height?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

I noticed the characters in my party can have vastly different amounts of HP depending on their class. My Soulhacker has 1,617 HP while my Lost Vanguard has 8,450 HP.

If I switch to a character with more HP, will it help me survive fall damage from greater heights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experimental testing, once the height reaches a certain threshold, fall damage will inflict enough damage to kill you regardless of how much HP your units have. I tested this with three different characters with different classes all in the same location and height.

1. [Taion](https://twitter.com/btwondercricket/status/1634529727674466304?s=20) - At lv79, he had 2973 HP. Fall damage dealt 4546HP
2. [Noah](https://twitter.com/btwondercricket/status/1634529823493324802?s=20) - At lv79, he had 8001HP. Fall damage dealt 12194HP
3. [Mio](https://twitter.com/btwondercricket/status/1634529919798743040?s=20) - At lv79, she had 3320HP. Fall damage dealt 5004HP

Calculating out the character's max HP and the fall damage that was dealt, all three characters took ~165% damage. Based that information, it appears that fall damage deals a percentage of the unit's max HP, which increases in relation to the height. Based on that, once the height reaches a threshold to deal 100% HP, your unit will not survive no matter how much HP they have (and as you can see in the video, the fall was not all that high comparatively speaking to the rest of the world.)

Comment: XC1 and XC2 do the same thing of "fall damage is a % of max HP". This means there's no way for the player to get around the max fall height by changing characters or attributes or whatever, which lets the devs design areas without having to worry about "what if they cheese this fall".